# react project works fine in local, but fails in production build

Tags: reactjs

when the project is startd with npm start, it works fine but when in ran build command `react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build` and served the project with serve -s build

it is giving error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (utils.js:48)
    at f ((index):1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (URL.js:4)
    at f ((index):1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webidl2js-wrapper.js:3)
    at f ((index):1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:3)
    at f ((index):1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (api.js:7)**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4yc8.png)

[Error In Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4yc8.png)

```
can any one suggest how to solve this problem.
```

Comment: Maybe you have a test running when trying to make the production build and this test ins't executed with npm start.  What is this utils.js file? Is it a file you wrote or something in a package you use?

Comment: Have you tried the `npm start` in an incognito window and check if the error is there? Im guessing it's a caching issue

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the code of `utils.js`?

Comment: utils.js was the file that got included from jsdom. it was not my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, utils.js was the file of jsdom and it was a server side dependency.Due to this the react was not able to build the project. Once i removed this dependency from my project, it was working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey, I have the same error, what do you mean you removed utils.js? I don't see any dependency called jsdom in my package.json, but its there in my node_modules folder. Its probably a transitive dependency. So should I just go into that folder and remove utils.js file?